# EMF Editing Domain Command Creation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf

I'm diving into EMF now, and have encountered the following problem:

I'm trying to remove fields from fieldset with following code:

```
 FieldElem ff = ds.getContent().getNestedFieldset().get(0).getField().get(0);

            Command remove = new RemoveCommand(editingDomain, nf, 
                           DescPackage.eINSTANCE.getNestedFieldsetElem_Field(), ff);
            editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute(remove);

            ff = ds.getContent().getNestedFieldset().get(0).getField().get(0);

            Command remove2 = RemoveCommand.create(editingDomain, nf, 
                    DescPackage.eINSTANCE.getNestedFieldsetElem_Field(), ff);
            editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute(remove2);

            ff = ds.getContent().getNestedFieldset().get(0).getField().get(0);

            Command remove3 = RemoveCommand.create(editingDomain, ff);
            editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute(remove3);
```

The first two commands works just fine, but third one not. I's not even adding to the command stack, and is not removing anything. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** As i've seen in debugger, execute method return UNEXECUTABLE_COMMAND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction `RemoveCommand.create(editingDomain, ff)` can be used only if `ff` as a container (ie `ff.eContainer != null`). The `eContainer` is set automatically by EMF when you add the object to a relation with containment property.

The `remove3` command does not work certainly because the `getField()` relation is not a containment relation.

Comment: Thank you very much! eContainer == null, as you predicted. How shouldi fix it? Is it related to the model setup? I've generated my model from XSD schema, and didn't change it much, aside from max/min elements.

Comment: @execc : I don't know how works generation from XSD. If you have an .ecore file, the containment can be set in the property view when the relation is selected. Be careful, when you activate the containment, the behavior of EMF changes, because an object can have only one container : so if you add an object to a containment list, and this object was already in a containment list, EMF removes silently the object from its previous list. It can be hard to debug.

Comment: here is my setup for model: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1aIvcp-aJHs/TzT22CtrhDI/AAAAAAAAAAc/6GZhtwlSfBk/s963/containment.JPG and it looks like field have an containment relation with fieldset. What's wrong?

Comment: @execc I thought `containment` was enough. Regenerate the model classes and check that `NestedFieldsetElemImpl.getField()` uses an `EObjectContainmentEList`. Also I've noticed some differences between my properties and yours, but I'm not sure it's related: I have derived:false, resolveProxies:true, transient:false, volatile:false.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've founded an answer:

As i've used and XSD as a source, the model was generated from this fragment:

```
<xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="field" type="fieldElem" />
            <xsd:element name="autofill-field" type="fieldElem" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="fieldset" type="fieldsetElem" />
            <xsd:element name="join-field" type="joinFieldElem"/>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
```

So the FieldsetElem, aren't contains FieldElem directly, instead the FieldElem is derieved from an appropriate FutureMap entry. So the correct code is:

```
Command remove = RemoveCommand.create(ed,  ed.getWrapper(fe));
```